# Typescript Interface Optional Method Property Undefined

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm following Pluralsites course on Typescript in Depth. When working with interfaces, I have the following:

```
interface Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    available: boolean;
    category: Category;
    pages: number;
    markDamaged: DamageLogger;
}

interface DamageLogger {
    (reason: string): void;
}
```

I am now declaring a book as in:

```
let myBook: Book = {
    id: 5,
    title: 'Pride and Prejudice',
    author: 'Jane Austen',
    available: true,
    category: Category.Fiction,
    pages: 250,
    markDamaged: (reason: string) => console.log('Damaged: ' + reason)
};

myBook.markDamaged('missing back cover');
```

All is well but as soon as I change the interface for the markDamaged to be optional as in:

```
interface Book {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
    available: boolean;
    category: Category;
    pages: number;
    markDamaged?: DamageLogger;
}
```

The compiler barks on this line:

```
myBook.markDamaged('missing back cover');
```

and says the markDamaged property is possibly undefined. I remove the question mark and all is well again.

Any ideas whats going on here? I'm using optional params elsewhere in the course with no issues but when working with interfaces, this is what I'm seeing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, since markDamaged is marked optional, it could not exist in the object. If it doesn't exist, it's undefined. So you need to check it exists before calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you state `markDamaged?: DamageLogger`, you mean that a `Book` may or may not have a `markDamaged` property. The compiler then forces you to check that a `Book` (including `myBook`) actually has `markDamaged` before it will let you call it. This check is only enabled when the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option is set.

This works

```
interface Book {
    markDamaged: DamageLogger
}
interface DamageLogger {
    (reason: string): void
}

let myBook: Book = {
    markDamaged: (reason: string) => console.log('Damaged: ' + reason)
}
// myBook: Book; it definitely has markDamaged
myBook.markDamaged('missing back cover')
```

This doesn't

```
interface Book { markDamaged?: DamageLogger }
// ...
// myBook: Book; Books do not definitely have markDamaged
myBook.markDamaged('...')
```

but this does

```
if(myBook.markDamaged) {
    // Now we know it's there, we can call it
    myBook.markDamaged('...')
}
```

This also works:

```
interface Book { markDamaged?: DamageLogger }
// don't say it's a Book
// inferred: myBook: { markDamaged: (reason: String) => void }
// TypeScript's type system is structural, not nominal
// The identity of a type is in it's structure, not name
// myBook's type says that it definitely has markDamaged
let myBook = { markDamaged: (reason: String) => console.log('Damaged: ' + reason) }
myBook.markDamaged('...')

function read(b: Book) {}
// myBook's type is a subtype of Book, because a Book can be missing markDamaged but myBook definitely has it.
read(myBook)
```

Comment: Man, this one is really weird. If make the pages property in the interface optional, I can call it no prob like:

myBook.pages = 10. Because 'markDamaged' is a method, it doesnt like it.

Comment: You are setting the property; so it will be created if it’s missing. It doesn’t matter whether it’s optional or not.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's not guaranteed to be defined. Check for it first and the compiler should stop complaining.

```
if (myBook && myBook.markDamaged) {
    myBook.markDamaged('missing back cover');
}
```